# How to explicitly test for a promise to resolve in QUnit

Tags: qunit

In QUnit, it is possible to check for a promise to [reject](https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/rejects/):

```
assert.rejects(Promise.reject(new Error("some error description")), "promise rejected");
```

However, there is no assert method to explicitly check for a promise to resolve. I know I can implicitly test for the promise to resolve like this:

```
QUnit.test("Promise will resolve", function(assert) {
  return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    assert.ok(true);
  });
});
```

In this case I'm not interested in any return value from the promise. The need for an `assert.ok(true)` (or specifying `expect(0)`) to prevent the "Expected at least one assertion" error, doesn't feel right. And when the promise rejects, I will not get a nice assert message along with the failed test.

Is there a reason something like `assert.resolves(promise[, message])` doesn't exist? Is there some other way to explicitly test for a promise to resolve?

Comment: I haven't seen that either. I think the reasoning is that if it resolves you want to check the data that it resolves with.